# Fetching values from databse depending on the options selected in multiple combo box

Tags: php

I have a combo box that allows multiple selection and i have another combo box.

Depending on the values selected from the first combo box, i need to display them in the second combo box.

My requirement scenario looks much like this example, let the first combo box contains a list of all states. Whenever a state is selected, all the cities in that state will be fetched from the database and displayed in the second combo box.

If we select multiple items(states) in the first combo box. The cities of the selected states should be displayed in the second combo box.

I thought of a solution for this, by storing all items selected in an array. Am not sure how to implement it. It will be of great help if anyone provides a working example.

I am new to PHP, so finding it difficult to implement. It will be of great help if anyone provides a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array suffix at yours state checkboxes. Here is small example. It is very basic but shows the idea.

```
<form method="post">
<table><tr><td>
<?
    // Sample array, you should use database query instead
    $statesArr = array('FL'=>'Florida','CA'=>'California','NY'=>'New York');

    foreach ($statesArr as $stateCode => $stateName) { 
        $checked = (count($_POST['states']) && in_array($stateCode,$_POST['states']))?'checked="checked"':''; // rechecking selected checkboxes
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="states[]"  value="'.$stateCode.'" '.$checked.'/>'.$stateName.'</label><br />';
    }

?>
</td><td>
    <?  if ($_POST && count($_POST['states'])) {
            echo '<select multiple="multiple">';
            $sql = "SELECT `CityName` FROM `Cities` WHERE `ParentStateCode` IN ('".implode("','",$_POST['states'])."')";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<option>'.$row['CityName'].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
    ?> 
    </td>
    </tr></table>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Look at the checkboxes name (name="states[]"). Adding [] after input's name makes it possible to use multiple inputs with same name and access its values on server side through array. So in your case we're having $_POST['states'] setted to Array(0=>'FL',1=>'NY');
Then we need just to implode this array's values into SQL query.
MySQL's construction WHERE `Field` IN (...) allows you to select cities from set of state codes, finishing deal. Challenge completed!
PS: sorry for my weak English.